# Array_push pushes invisible element, and only works on second push

Tags: php, arrays

I had a problem with my array_push, that i noticed.

So what i'm doing.:
I have a site, where there are some buttons with a specific value.

Each value is getting fetched from a database.

I have a session called test, that get's converted to an array(to store multiple in the same array)

Everytime one of the buttons are clicked, the value for that specific button, is getting pushed to the array.

But, i can ONLY see that it has been pushed at the second try.

```
[test] => Array( [0] => 21304 )
```

This is what i see, after second try. But my array count, says that there are 2 elements, in that array.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
        $_SESSION['test'] = array();
        $array_merge = array_push($_SESSION['test'], $_POST['process']);
    }
}
```

The `$_POST['process']` is the button with the unique value.

Can somebody maybe see what I'm doing wrong here?

Kind regards

Comment: When you try for the first time. do you enter in the if statement?

Comment: What do you see on the first try?

Answer (score 1):

You are only adding to the `$_SESSION['test']` array if `$_SESSION['test']` was not previously set.

So you need to always add an occurance to the session array and only initialise the session array if it was not previously set

```
session_start();

// ...

if(isset($_POST['process'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
        $_SESSION['test'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['test'][] = $_POST['process'];
}
```

> NOTE from the manual
>
> If you use array_push() to add one element to the array, it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.